# Failsafe withFallback(): why kotlin compiler fails to infer lambda type?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, type-inference, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have following in my kotlin code:

```
return Failsafe.with<Boolean>(retryPolicy)
        // Here I want fall back to false
        .withFallback { -> false} // Does not work
        .get { ->
            publish(event)
            true
        }
```

Kotlin compiler complains that:

> Error:(89, 14) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:
>
> public final fun withFallback(p0: (() -> Boolean!)!): SyncFailsafe! defined in net.jodah.failsafe.SyncFailsafe
>
> public final fun withFallback(p0: (() -> Unit)!): SyncFailsafe! defined in net.jodah.failsafe.SyncFailsafe

But this way it works:

```
val fallback: () -> Boolean = { false }

return Failsafe.with<Boolean>(retryPolicy)
        // Here I want fall back to false
        .withFallback(fallback) // Works
        .get { ->
            publish(event)
            true
        }
```

Could somebody explain me why it does not work with lambda literal outside brackets? And how to make it work with lambda inline?

Comment: Try to remove the `->`, they are only necessary when you are defining parameters in front of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
val fallback: () -> Unit = { -> false }
```

you'll see it compiles as well (it just discards the result). So `{ -> false}` can be used for both types `() -> Boolean` and `() -> Unit` and the compiler doesn't know which you want.

So to use a lambda, specify the desired type there:

```
.withFallback({ -> false} as () -> Boolean)
```

or create an extension function without an overload, e.g.:

```
fun <T, F> FailsafeConfig<T, F>.withFallbackT(fallback: () -> T) = withFallback(fallback)

return Failsafe.with<Boolean>(retryPolicy)
    .withFallbackT { -> false}...
```